# Panel control gradient fill not working

Tags: c#, background, controls

I have a panel control that I want to fill up with gradient. I have the following code:

```
Brush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(pnlBody.ClientRectangle, Color.Black, Color.White, LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal);
pnlBody.CreateGraphics().FillRectangle(brush, pnlBody.ClientRectangle);
```

But it has no effect. If I replace pnlBody with form, then it colors the form fine, but not panel. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: where did you put this code ?

Comment: @Tigran in formLoad event, thanks!

Comment: you have to apply graidens inside OnPaint override of the Control, enable double buffering and distable background repaint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Panel control will paint itself with its Paint event.  Which wipes out anything you paint by using CreateGraphics().  You'll need to use its Paint event instead.  This will however produce flicker, you'll see it paint its background first.  Panel is also optimized to act as a container control with low impact paint overhead, you'll see it not repaint itself when it is resized.  An issue when you anchor it to the right or bottom and resize the form.

To fix these issues, you should derive your own class from Panel.  Add a new class to your project and paste this code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class GradientPanel : Panel {
    public GradientPanel() {
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
    }
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) {
        using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, 
                   Color.Black, Color.White, LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal)) {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se) {
        this.Invalidate();
        base.OnScroll(se);
    }
}
```

Build + Build.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form, replacing the original panel.  You can get creative by adding properties that select the gradient start and end colors, producing a more generally useful control that can be reused in other projects.  Do avoid the panel showing a scrollbar, you cannot make the scrolling look decent because of the Windows "Show window content while dragging" feature.  The effect is somewhat similar to the pogo.

Comment: Can I use this as a common method to apply this style to selected panels in the whole application ?